# Comparar duas datas e horas e verificar se uma é maior que a outra typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, data

Criei uma função que recebe uma conta, preciso verificar se uma propriedade `conta.venc_token` é maior que a data de hoje, se for, retornar `true`(pois é um token invalido), do contrário, retornar `false`.

Eu tentei dessa forma:

```
  verificaVenceuConta(conta):boolean{
    var data = conta.venc_token
    console.log(data);
    console.log(new Date())
    if(data > new Date()){
      console.log("entrou no if")
      return true
    }else{
      console.log("entrou no false")
      return false
    }
  }
```

Porém o formato que retorna do meu backend é muito diferente do formato que o javascript gera a data atual.

Nos `console.log` eu tenho:

**Formato do meu backend:**

```
10/04/2019 18:27:38
```

**Formato que o javascript gera:**

```
Wed Apr 10 2019 14:28:55 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)
```

Gostaria de saber uma forma de comparar. Essa forma que eu encontrei consegue comparar corretamente as datas e horas? Pelos testes que eu fiz sempre retorna no `else` (false).

Comment: Se `console.log(data);` imprime `10/04/2019 18:27:38`, provavelmente é uma string (que vc deve converter para `Date`) - verifique `typeof(data)` só para ter certeza. Pois ao imprimir um `Date`, ele sempre é mostrado nesse formato "Wed Apr 10 etc...". Outro detalhe é saber se 18:27 está no mesmo fuso horário do frontend, senão não tem como fazer a conversão de forma confiável.

Comment: Sim, é do tipo string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A forma mais prática que eu conheço de converter texto em data é referenciando [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

```
moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:m:s'); 

moment("20111031", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow();

moment("20120620", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow();

moment().startOf('day').fromNow();       

moment().endOf('day').fromNow();
```

Answer (score 1):

Consegui dessa forma:

```
  verificaVenceuConta(conta):boolean{

    var partesData = conta.venc_token.split("/")
    partesData[1] = partesData[1] - 1;
    partesData[2] = partesData[2].substring(0,4)
    partesData.push(conta.venc_token.substring(11,19))
    partesData[3] = partesData[3].split(":")
    let dataMontada = new Date(partesData[2], partesData[1], partesData[0], partesData[3][0], partesData[3][1], partesData[3][2])

    if(dataMontada < new Date()){
      return true
    }else{
      return false
    }

  }
```

Não é muito atrativa, mas foi a forma fácil que consegui sem uso de frameworks

Comment: Não esqueça que no JavaScript meses são indexados em zero (janeiro é zero, fevereiro é 1, etc), então tem que subtrair 1 do mês antes de passar para o construtor de `Date` :-)

Comment: obrigado pelo comentário, vou fazer aqui